# How to fade in and fade out text on a timer using css animations

Tags: css, css-animations

I am needing to fadeIn a list of text and then fade each one out individually using css. Here is an example I did using javascript. Any help would be appreciated. I have read some examples of how to animate stuff with css but do not know the best practices or anything to complex.

I am thinking I need to create a wrapper div with a overflow of hidden and a separate div with all the text that is position absolute in the wrapper. Then animate the .text div up or down to show the text. I have no experience with css animations.

Here is what I want to do but with css not javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/trav5567/8ejqsywu/

Here is my javascript:

```
var quotes = $(".whoiam").find('h2');
        var quoteIndex = -1;
        quotes.hide();
        function showNextQuote() {
            ++quoteIndex;
            console.log(quoteIndex);
            if(quoteIndex === quotes.length){
                console.log($(this));
                //console.log('index greater than or equal to h2 length');
                //$(this).fadeIn('200');
            }else{
                console.log('Kepp going');
            quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
                .fadeIn(500)
                .delay(500, checkIndex(quoteIndex,quotes.length))
                .fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
            }
        }showNextQuote();
        function checkIndex(index, length){
            var length = length-1
            if(index === length){
                console.log('check good');
                end();
            }
        }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="splash-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <h1>Travis M. Heller</h1>
                <div class='whoiam'>
                    <h2>Front End Developer</h2>
                    <h2>Illustrator</h2>
                    <h2>Web Master</h2>
                    <h2>Front End Developer</h2>//This value will be the last to show on loop.
                </div>
                <button class="btn center gotoPortfolio">ENTER</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An experiment with just css animations: http://jsfiddle.net/8ejqsywu/6/

There is one animation which moves the text list verticaly, and another which fades in and out the text. The difficulty was to synchronize them!

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:48px;
}
.whoiam{
    -webkit-animation: move;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: step-start;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s
}
h2{ height:48px;margin:0;padding:0}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% { margin-top: 0em; }
    25% { margin-top: -48px; }
    50% {margin-top: -96px;}
    75% {margin-top: -144px; }
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}

h2{
    -webkit-animation: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, any thoughts on making it end on the last one? I need the animation to stop at the last h2 element.

Comment: juste change the values of -webkit-animation-iteration-count; http://jsfiddle.net/8ejqsywu/5/

Comment: but you will have to set the value of webkit-animation-iteration-count of the fade effect dynamicaly, to correspond to the number of element you have